# How can I differentiate between a number and a symbol in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, input

I need to make two different error messages: one if the user inputs a number, one if they input an operand (it's for an equation calculator). 
My code so far is below:

```
#If user just presses enter:
if len(theParts) == 0 :
    print("You have not entered an equation. Please, try again!")

# If input is a word:
elif equation.isalpha():
    print("You have entered a word instead of an equation!")

elif len(theParts) == 1 :
    print("You have only entered an operand/operator. Please, try again!") 

elif len(theParts) == 2 :
    print("You have not entered a complete equation. Please, try again!")
```

I also tried doing equation.isnumeric() but that includes symbols as well. Is there a way to differentiate the numbers and symbols, or do I have to do something like this for each operand:

```
elif '*' in theParts and len(theParts) == 1:
    print("error")
```

Comment: Essentially you need to create tokens then analyse those tokens. Writing a parser is a tough task so I'd recommend looking into something like pyparsing to help you get this done.

Comment: I'm trying `isnumeric()` right now and it isn't accepting symbols like `*`, `.`, `/`, and `+`.

Comment: you can use tokenizers

Comment: read through [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two ways to do this:

#### 1. Remove allowed non-digit characters and use [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit).

```python
"12345".isdigit()                   # true
"123.45".replace('.', '').isdigit() # true
"12*4.3".isdigit()                  # false
```

#### 2. Define your own set of allowed characters

```python
def is_good_number(s):
    for char in s:
        if not char in '1234567890.':
            return False
    return True

is_good_number("12345")  # true
is_good_number("123.45") # true
is_good_number("12*4.3") # false
```

Comment: My issue is that it needs to detect numbers with decimals too. In my code in general, I'll get the error message working for if the user enters just a symbol, but then if they enter a number they'll get the error saying they entered a symbol.